# THREE.js make transparent objects that have other objects in background

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hy,

I want to make a room in three.js and I want the walls that have objects behind them (from the pov of the camera) to become transparent (.5 opacity) as I rotate the room.

To clarify a little bit:

> Imagine you have a room. That room has walls. In that room you insert
>   furniture. Camera looks at the room and I want the walls to be
>   transparent only if from the pov of the camera they have other objects
>   behind (so you can see throw walls the room). The walls in the back
>   should have opacity 1. So anywhere you move the camera (and look at
>   the room) you can see all the elements (otherwise some walls will
>   block the view)
>   [image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/tp2f2oo4/?

Comment: YES and no. That is VERY satisfying, but I ultimately need to know if a object has behind it another object so I can make this transparent. As you can see in the image, the top of the wall is not transparent, and I want that transparent too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide a lot of detail with regards to how you are moving the camera. But it can be done fairly easily. All meshes have a material property that has an opacity.

Here is a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Komsomol/xu2mjwdk/

I added the entire OrbitControls.js inside and added a boolean;

```
var doneMoving = false;
```

Which I added in the mouseup and mousedown of the OrbitControls. Just to capture when we are not moving the camera.

There are some specific options that need to be added in the renderer and the object.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha:true,
    transparent: true
});
```

The object

```
torusMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
torusMat.needsUpdate = true;
torusMat.transparent = true;
```

And finally add some control code in the Animate method to kick off whatever changes you want.

```
if(doneMoving){
   torusMat.opacity = 0.5;
} else {
    torusMat.opacity = 1;
}
```

That's about it. This should give you enough of an idea how to implement this.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was looking for. Imagine you have a room. That room has walls. In that room you insert furniture. Camera looks at the room and I want the walls to be transparent only if from the pov of the camera they have other objects behind (so you can see throw walls the room). The walls in the back should have opacity 1. So anywhere you move the camera (and look at the room) you can see all the elements (otherwise some walls will block the view).

Comment: You should be more clear when asking then. You set your WALLS of the room to only render the BACKSIDE surface. This is done in the materials. side: THREE.BackSide. This would mean your camera will only see them when its behind but not infront.

Comment: I am sorry that is what you understood from what I was describing. THREE.BackSide is very nice, but does not solve my problem 100%.

Comment: You can do some kind of ray casting, against all the objects that can be behind a wall, and see if the wall is closer...

Comment: I had a similar problem to what this answer is getting at. It didn't directly solve my problem, but led me to the right answer (and I never would have found the renderer settings).  I had two STL files loaded as MeshPhongMaterial, playing with the transparency using the Material Browser example (https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/material-browser.html#MeshStandardMaterial).
For me, I couldn't get the internal STL to render while looking through the semi-opaque outer STL, until I added the "alphaToCoverage" parameter as True.
Cheers, Komsomol!